# Changing Size of Legend in Altair

Tags: python, gis, data-science, vega-lite, altair

I'm loving Altair for creating choropleth maps! My biggest problem, however, is I cannot figure out how to change the size of the legend. I've read through the documentation and tried several things to no avail.

Here's an example using the [unemployment map by county](https://altair-viz.github.io/gallery/choropleth.html) from Altair's docs. I added a 'config' layer to change the font size for the title on both the map and the legend. Note the .configure_legend() part of the code within "config".

```
counties = alt.topo_feature(data.us_10m.url, 'counties')
source = data.unemployment.url

foreground = alt.Chart(counties).mark_geoshape(
    ).encode(
    color=alt.Color('rate:Q', sort="descending",  scale=alt.Scale(scheme='plasma'), legend=alt.Legend(title="Unemp Rate", tickCount=6))
).transform_lookup(
    lookup='id',
    from_=alt.LookupData(source, 'id', ['rate'])
).project(
    type='albersUsa'
).properties(
    title="Unemployment Rate by County",
    width=500,
    height=300
)

config = alt.layer(foreground).configure_title(fontSize=20, anchor="middle").configure_legend(titleColor='black', titleFontSize=14) 

config
```

Here's what the image should look like:

[image]

If I change the size of the map like this:

```
counties = alt.topo_feature(data.us_10m.url, 'counties')
source = data.unemployment.url

foreground = alt.Chart(counties).mark_geoshape(
    ).encode(
    color=alt.Color('rate:Q', sort="descending",  scale=alt.Scale(scheme='plasma'), legend=alt.Legend(title="Unemp Rate", tickCount=6))
).transform_lookup(
    lookup='id',
    from_=alt.LookupData(source, 'id', ['rate'])
).project(
    type='albersUsa'
).properties(
    title="Unemployment Rate by County",
    width=900,
    height=540
)

config = alt.layer(foreground).configure_title(fontSize=20, anchor="middle").configure_legend(titleColor='black', titleFontSize=14) 

config
```

The legend stays the same size, so that it now looks tiny in comparison to the map:

[image]

Alternatively, if I make the map size tiny, the legend will be huge!

[image]

I've tried about a dozen different things to no avail.

Anyone have a solution to this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As you have seen, the legend has a default size in pixels that is constant regardless of the size of the chart. If you would like to adjust it, you can use the `configure_legend()` chart method.

In Altair 3.0 or later, the following arguments are the relevant ones for adjusting the size of the legend gradient:

```
chart.configure_legend(
    gradientLength=400,
    gradientThickness=30
)
```

Comment: Thanks, jakevdp. Is this something that has been recently fixed in 3.0? I'm pretty sure I tried gradientHeight and gradientWidth in 2.4 and it didn't work, but this code definitely works in 3.0. However, it looks like all kinds of other things changed as well. For instance, now the color scheme looks very different :)

Comment: Legends are one of the big changes from Vega-Lite 2 to 3: there are now options for creating both horizontal and vertical legends, and the configuration options have been updated and renamed accordingly.

Answer (score 4):

The first answer is super close but missing the most important piece for changing the font size in the legend. Use the code snippet below to adjust font size of text in the legend.

```js
.configure_legend(
titleFontSize=18,
labelFontSize=15
)
```