# Altair - Remove ellipsis ("...") from legend with long strings

Tags: python, legend, altair

Via Python, I am using Altair to plot bar graphs. I was able to move the legend to be at the top, however, it is adding ellipsis (i.e. "...") at the end of each legend because my strings are too long. Is there any work around this? I tried `gradientlength` but it does not do the trick. Also, and as my strings are pretty long, would be possible to jump lines between each legend?

```
alt.Chart(df).mark_bar().encode(
    x=alt.X("fund:O", axis=alt.Axis(title=None, labels=False, ticks=False)),
    y=alt.Y("value:Q", axis=alt.Axis(title="Percentage", grid=True)),
    color=alt.Color("fund:N", legend=alt.Legend(orient="top")),
    tooltip=["data point info:O", "fund:N", "value", "bucket"],
    column=alt.Column(
        "bucket:N",
        header=alt.Header(title=None, labelOrient="bottom", labelAngle=x_angle),
        sort=list_to_sort,
        spacing=40,
    ),
).configure_view(stroke="transparent").interactive()
```

This is how it current looks like:

[image]

One example of the legends is:

- "Morningstar - FOUSA08OZU: Vanguard Total Bond Market II Index Fund Institutional Shares"

Documentation is here - https://altair-viz.github.io/user_guide/generated/core/altair.Legend.html

Similar ish question - [Changing Size of Legend in Altair](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55443485/changing-size-of-legend-in-altair)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to show the full legend label instead of truncating it with `...` you can set the `labelLimit` parameter to a higher number. You might also want to check out `labelOverlap`, `labelPadding`, and `direction` for the second part of your question regarding overlapping labels.

Comment: Yep, that did the trick. I end up using ```color = alt.Color('fund:N',legend=alt.Legend(orient='top',labelLimit = 400,direction = 'vertical'))```